# Android view clickable when DrawerLayout is shown

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In my application when I opening `DrawerLayout` below `view` is clickable, I tired to read about this problem and try to fix, but I can't, my `DrawerLayout` have to parent as middle view and menu items.

this is **xml layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/application_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/simcard_lists"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_menu"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_simcards"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/filter_by_simcard_code"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                    android:shadowDx="3"
                    android:shadowDy="3"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:text="{fa-filter}"
                    android:textColor="#9f24b8"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_buys_lists"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:shadowColor="#22000000"
                    android:shadowDx="3"
                    android:shadowDy="3"
                    android:shadowRadius="1"
                    android:text="{fa-check}"
                    android:textColor="#9f24b8"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/about_us"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

it means `recyclerview` items clickable when `DrawerLayout` is shown

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly

Comment: @Raghunandan `recyclerview` items clickable when `DrawerLayout` is shown

Comment: put android:clickable="true" in the layout which represents the drawer.The layout with android:layout_gravity="start".

Comment: @SagarGangawane thanks, problem resolved :)

Comment: @SagarGangawane please reply to my post and let me to accept it

Comment: @mahdipishguy what you want now from me i did not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put android:clickable="true" in the layout which represents the drawer.The layout with android:layout_gravity="start"